# Issues with cufon canvas size

Tags: html, css, menu, cufon

I have got a test site [test site](http://b2b.tangent-design.com/) on which i have used cufon to display font on the top navigation menu, it works fine , but if you navigate to [blog section](http://b2b.tangent-design.com/blog/) , the menu text is disturbed, I have spend hours to figure out with no success, any ideas how to get the menu fonts aligned on blog section like all the other pages.

Thanks

Comment: offtopic question: why use cufon?? Use `@font-face`, it's far better.

Comment: @font-face works on all browsers?

Comment: of course it does. I post it as answer if you like.

Comment: I just looked at cufon and it looks like they are now using @font-face instead of canvas. If you are still using a canvas version I recommend you update your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using `@font-face` instead of cufon.

It works in [virtually every browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=@font-face) (IE-Support from at least version 5.5 on, yay).

For the lazy guys, Google has a vast variety of free-of-charge Webfonts **[here](http://www.google.com/webfonts)**

If you want something special, you have to use the font of your choice (if you have the copyright or use a free font), and convert it to the formats you need (there are tons of converters out on the web).

After that you take a look for example at [Paul Irish's Article about @font-face](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/). And there you go.

Effectively it's something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Graublau Web';
  src: url('GraublauWeb.eot');
  src: local('☺'),
    url("GraublauWeb.woff") format("woff"),
    url("GraublauWeb.otf") format("opentype"),
    url("GraublauWeb.svg#grablau") format("svg");
}
```

Comment: the only downside with font-face is lack of anti-aliasing... cufon seems to handle this by means of scaling.